# Operator norm in C*-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, c-star-algebras

I came across this in a blog post.

Let $A$ be a subset of $n \times n$ complex matrices (which can be viewed as a $C^*$-algebra). Then they write $\|A\|$ (which I assume to be operator norm) as $\max_{s\ \in \text{ states on A}} s(A)$. I think states in a $C^*$-algebra are positive linear functionals with norm at most 1, but I wasn't sure why the operator norm of $A$ can be viewed as a maximum over states on the algebra operating on $A$? Could someone clarify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the usual way of identifying an algebra of matrices (or more generally operators on a Hilbert space) as a $C^*$-algebra, the norm is the operator norm.  However, one would usually take the scalars to be complex, so I question whether you really want **real** matrices here.

Your statement about states is wrong.  For the $C^*$ algebra of $n \times n$ complex matrices, the states are convex combinations of the pure states corresponding to unit vectors:
$$ \varphi_v(A) = v^* A v $$ 
For example, if $n=2$, the matrix $$A = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$$
has $\varphi_v(A) = \overline{v_1} v_2$, and $|\varphi_v(A)| \le 1/2$ while 
$\|A\| = 1$.  What is true is that if $A$ is a **positive** member of the $C^*$-algebra (corresponding to a positive-definite matrix) there is a state $\varphi$ with $\varphi(A) = \|A\|$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed I need complex and not real matrices. Just to be sure, why do we know that states on the C* algebra of $n\times n$ matrices are convex combination  of the pure states? Is it obvious somehow?
Also, how is the positivity used in the argument that there *exists* a state that ensures $\phi(A)=||A||$?

Comment: The states form a compact convex set, whose extreme points are the pure states.  In finite dimensions, every member of a compact convex set is a convex combination of extreme points of the set (Krein-Milman theorem and [Caratheodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory's_theorem_%28convex_hull%29)).

Comment: I see! Thanks. So about the second question, where is the complete positivity used in showing there exists a state that attains the operator norm?

Comment: I think it works for normal elements (not just positive ones) in general C$^\ast$-algebras and is based on how one proves that there are "enough" states: one uses non-emptyness of spectra and build a state thereby, then uses that for, normal elements $a\in A$, $\Vert a \Vert = r(a)$ (spectral radius).